# SSRS 2012 MATRIX TOTAL DYNAMIC COLUMNS BY COLUMN HEADING

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Simple Q:
In SSRS 2012:  require a matrix with column totals derived from the dynamic column headings;

e.g.

```
Period  1       2       3       Total   Total
Type    Act Bud Act Bud Act Bud  Act    Bud
Total   10  9   10  9   10  9    30      27
```

is this possible in SSRS?

Can easily get the total of the sum of columns -(57) but not split by type.

Thank You.

```
data is grouped ;
Business Unit - Row Group
Account Type - Row Group
Month Period - Column Group
Amount_Type (Act, Bud) - Column Group
The Aggregate is Amount
```

Tks

Comment: Yes, It is possible. Add an image showing your matrix or include the structure of your dataset in order to help you.

Comment: alejandro - as a humble new user with no points - I can't add an image!

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the structure of your dataset?

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing the structure of your dataset I think you can add two columns outside the columns groups at the right side and use these expression to calculate the respective total:

For `Actual` total:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "Act",Fields!Amount.Value,0))
```

For `Budget` total:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "Bud",Fields!Amount.Value,0))
```

**UPDATE:** Try setting the scope of the SUM function.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "Act",Fields!Amount.Value,0),"DataSetName")
```

Replace DataSetName by the actual name of your dataset.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: that gives #error - is it the scope of the formula?

Comment: @Lazarus, without see the structure of your tablix I can't tell you if that is the correct scope. Try setting the scope of the sum function to the entire dataset as pointed in my edit.

Comment: This revision gives the total sum of all amounts for the dataset in each row i.e.scope is not applied to the row.

Comment: @Lazarus, could you explain which groups affect the cell where you used the expression?